# pygsheets last access or last modified timestamp

Tags: python, bash, pygsheets

I'm looking for the most efficient method to check if & when Google Sheets have been modified using pygsheets.

My current method:

(Py):

```
gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_file=gServiceAccAuthFile, retries=1)
# Open spreadsheet
sh = gc.open_by_key(gSheetKey)
# Open Worksheet
wks = sh.worksheet_by_title(gWorksheetName)
# Export as CSV
wks.export(pygsheets.ExportType.CSV, path=outputDir + '/', filename=outputFileName)
```

(BASH):

```
compare_sha() {
# Compare Previous Sha to New File Sha
log_output "Original SHA: ${1}\tNew SHA: ${2}"
if [[ $1 == $2 ]]; then return 1; else return 0; fi
}
if compare_sha $origSha $newSha || [[ "$force" == '1' ]];
then ...
else ...
fi
```

But this feels clunky. And requires download of the full sheet (checking every 60 secs)

Is there a better method directly integrated into pygsheets or python? Is there a more efficient way in bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pygsheets spreadsheet model has an updated property which will give the timestamp in wich the sheet was last updated.

`updated_time = sh.updated`

Comment: thank you. Could you tell me if this is only `user` updated? Every time I run an export the sheet history actually shows me that the `service account` is technically an update - even though it's a read action

Comment: Apologies - where this does indeed show then the Spreadsheet was updated, there doesn't appear to be a function which allows to check when the worksheet was updated? `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./testing-pull-GSheets-CSV.py", line 51, in <module>
    print(wks.updated)
AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'updated'`

Comment: AFAIK there is no option in the api to get the time when a worksheet was modified.

Comment: The updated time is retried using the drive api, see https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files for more details